# Find empty rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to scan a document, find where there is empty rows so I can add a page break when necessary.

For i = 1 to End of the document
I look at the value of the cells(i) and get if it is empty. The problem is with merged cells.
Let's say the range 1 to 5 is merged, and full of text. The code will tell me cells(1) is not empty but cells (2) and further are empty.

I believe the way to solve this would be to get if the cell is merged, get the end of the merge, and get i to be equal to it so it doesn't scan those row.

Any thought on the subject ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Here is my first thought - read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much answered your own question.

`ActiveCell.MergedArea` gives you the merged range and
`ActiveCell.MergedCells` returns True if the cell belongs to a merged range. You could work a solution from there.

The cell below a merge range would be:

```
ActiveCell.MergedArea.Offset(1)
```

I'm assuming you are working by selecting the ranges. For future reference, posting your codes and your previous approaches is helpful to people reading your questions